# how to get the class type in lua / translation from python

Tags: python, class, lua, torch

I am trying to find something analogous to the class in lua. In python, I would do:

```
a = {}
type(a)
>>>> dict
```

So I have the object vocab in lua. When I print the object, I get:

```
print(vocab)
>>> {
3 : 20
o : 72
m : 70
d : 61
( : 9
}
```

how can I get lua to spit the object, something analogous to the type() in python? - which will give you the class of the object

Comment: "So I have the object vocab in lua:" That's not Lua. Maybe that Python, maybe not. But it's certainly not Lua. It's also unclear what you're actually trying to do. Possibly because you don't actually say what `type` from Python actually does.

Comment: Hi Nicol - vocab is indeed Lua. type(a) in python will give you the class of the object.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `vocab`. The part that's not Lua is the table you create afterwards. Lua uses `name = value,` syntax for table declarations; the table you show would yield a syntax error.

Comment: the table is indeed lua. What you see is what you get if you print vocab - print(vocab)

Comment: You didn't say that the rest was the *result* of printing it. You put that in the same codeblock as the `print` statement. The obvious inference being that it's the same language as the rest. If you wanted to denote that it was the result of the Lua script, you should have made that more clear.

Comment: A pedantic point of view: `vocab` is a variable. Variables don't have types. And, from your Python example, it would seem that you simply need to read "dict" (Python) as "table" (Lua). Other than that, @NicolBolas gives you a real answer.

Comment: hi Tom, no - I really wanted to know the class. It might be a misconception  as a result of trying to experience lua from a python lens. But in python, knowing the class is very useful - you then know which methods you can use. I was wondering if there is anything similar in lua.

Comment: hi Nicol, ok got it. I changed the thread slightly, please let me know if it is more clear now.

Comment: "know which methods you can use": from documentation or code or content-assist/IntelliSense?

Comment: from documentation, or you may already know which methods you can use with, say, a list, which are different from the methods you can use with a dictionary - I believe both data structures would be basically tables in lua.

Comment: Your best bet would be to read the documentation for the function that returns the object. (I'm not familiar with Torch, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There are 8 types in `Lua`](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.html): nil, boolean, number, string, function, thread, **table** and **userdata**. You can find out which of these basic types your object belongs to using built-in `type()` function:

```
type('Hello world')                    == 'string'
type(3.14)                             == 'number'
type(true)                             == 'boolean'
type(nil)                              == 'nil'
type(print)                            == 'function'
type(coroutine.create(function() end)) == 'thread'
type({})                               == 'table'
type(torch.Tensor())                   == 'userdata'
```

Note that the type of `torch.Tensor` is userdata. That makes sense since `torch` library is written in C.

> The type userdata is provided to allow arbitrary C data to be stored
>   in Lua variables. A userdata value is a pointer to a block of raw
>   memory. Userdata has no predefined operations in Lua, except
>   assignment and identity test.
>
> The metatable for the userdata is put in the registry, and the __index
>   field points to the table of methods so that the object:method()
>   syntax will work.

So, dealing with a userdata object, we do not know what it is but have a list of its methods and can invoke them.

It would be great if custom objects had some mechanism (a method or something) to see their custom types. And guess what? Torch objects have one:

```
t = torch.Tensor()
type(t)       == 'userdata' # Because the class was written in C
torch.type(t) == 'torch.DoubleTensor'
# or
t:type()      == 'torch.DoubleTensor'
```

Speaking of `Torch`. It has its own object system emulator, and you are free to create some torch classes yourself and check their types the same way. For `Lua`, however, such classes/objects are nothing more than ordinary tables.

```
local A = torch.class('ClassA')
function A:__init(val)
    self.val = val
end

local B, parent = torch.class('ClassB', 'ClassA')
function B:__init(val)
    parent.__init(self, val)
end

b = ClassB(5)
type(b)       == 'table' # Because the class was written in Lua
torch.type(b) == 'ClassB'
b:type() # exception; Custom Torch classes have no :type() method by defauld
```

Comment: awesome response Alexander - this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

It is said that Lua defines "mechanisms, not policies". Classes would be a "policy". You can implement the effect of classes however you like; Lua provides many mechanisms that could be used to do so. But Lua has no single way of declaring such a construct.

Lua's `type` standard method will only return the broad category of a Lua value: number, string, table, etc. And since Lua has only one kind of data structure (table), every kind of class (not generated from C) would be of the "table" type.

This has the side effect of making it difficult in Lua to use someone else's policies. For example, if Torch has a way to distinguish its own "classes" from regular tables, that would work. But it wouldn't be able to distinguish some *other* class implementation from a regular table.

So there's no general way to distinguish a table from some form of "class".

Comment: When using a particular class system, you could possibly write a function that gives a "class name" and a list of "methods" (fields with values of type function).